# Public Perforce Open Source Repositories?

Tags: version-control, repository, perforce

While there are many open source repositories using CVS, SVN, and git, I'd like to know if there are any built atop Perforce, as I've been happily using that for CM at home for many years now.

Perforce provides a [public depot](http://public.perforce.com), but the projects hosted there appear to be strongly Perforce-oriented. What I'm working on has nothing to do with Perforce, I just like their product. The company provides a free license for hosting an open source project, but I have no interest in maintaining my own server out on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think public hosting currently aligns with Perforce's business model.

If you take a look at their licensing agreement, linked from here:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/opensource-faq.html

... you'll notice that it's only valid for one year, anyway. If you want to "go public" with your code, you might consider trying an import utility, such as p42svn:

http://p42svn.tigris.org/

Comment: The Perforce Open Source licence no longer limited to 12-months and can  be renewed by resubmitting the application. I am considering requesting a license and making various tools that I've created for Game Development open source.